# How to get UserHostAddress in .Net Framework 4.6

Tags: c#, .net

I want to retrieve the IP address of the user who has logged in using C# .Net Framework 4.6.

I have written the following code:

```
var ipaddress = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

but the ipaddress contains ::1. How can I get the full address. I am just only testing the code in the localhost. I have IIS7 installed.and .Net 2015 Framework 4.6.

Comment: `::1` is the IPv6 loopback address for localhost, so what you are getting is entirely expected.

Comment: (and also, you're getting IPv6 loopback, not v4)

Answer (score 1):

`::1` is a correct address.

> I am just only testing the code in the localhost.

localhost has two IP addresses on Windows (usually). 127.0.0.1, and ::1. The former is the IPv4 loopback address, and the latter is the IPv6 version, abbreviated.

IPv6 is preferred by default for localhost, and since you have an IPv6 capable browser, it uses the IPv6 address.

If you were to set up your web application to be available over a local intranet, then try accessing it from a different computer, then the IP address would be be the IP of the "remote" computer.

Comment: But here in Framework 4.6 error occurs, I think the above code doesn't support with framework 4.6.Need to find alternative code that support FW4.6 .